# Mutating via dplyr by a particular set of indices

Tags: r

I am working with a dataframe which follows a pattern of:

```
Key     Data
Loc     Place1
Value1  6
Value2  7
Loc     Place2
Value3  8
Loc     Place3
Value1  9
Value2  10
Loc     Place4
Value3  11
```

It is a rough dataset where a pattern exists - in this example, rows within `sep(1,100,by=5)` would identify the first location of an observation. My goal is to adjust the key in those positions to be different such as `LocA` rather than `Loc` in order for a `spread(key,value)` to provide me with unique observations I can use for further analysis:

```
LocA   Value1 Value2  Loc    Value3
Place1      6      7  Place2      8
Place3      9     10  Place4     11
```

I have been using `dplyr` and a chain of other mutates and selects to get to this point so I'm hoping to remain in the chain. I can see how I can do it with a appropriate subsetting outside of the chain but am having difficulty wrapping my head around a `dplyr` solution.

Comment: `. %>% mutate(grp = rep(seq(1, 100, by = 5), each = 5)) %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(Key = paste0(Key, grp))` might be a start, ugly as it seems.

Comment: I neglected to note that I did create an id/grp column such as you show - the problem is only changing the first `Loc` of each group to the same new key name with all other keys remaining the same. I'm going to give it some more thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data:

```
df <- structure(list(Key = c("Loc", "Value1", "Value2", "Loc", "Value3", 
"Loc", "Value1", "Value2", "Loc", "Value3"), Data = c("Place1", 
"6", "7", "Place2", "8", "Place3", "9", "10", "Place4", "11")), .Names = c("Key", 
"Data"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is this workable?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 5) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(
    Key = ifelse(! duplicated(Key), Key, paste0(Key, "A"))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(Key, Data) %>%
  select(-grp)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
#      Loc   LocA Value1 Value2 Value3
# *  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
# 1 Place1 Place2      6      7      8
# 2 Place3 Place4      9     10     11
```

Comment: Fantastic. It also accommodates something I overlooked -- I have another duplicate key (representing other attributes associated with LocA). My apologies for not providing the data in a nicer format as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this. I admit this one won't scale as good as the one from r2evans above.

```
df <- structure(list(Key = c("Loc", "Value1", "Value2", "Loc", "Value3", 
"Loc", "Value1", "Value2", "Loc", "Value3"), Data = c("Place1", 
"6", "7", "Place2", "8", "Place3", "9", "10", "Place4", "11")), .Names = c("Key", 
"Data"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
library(tidry)

df %>% 
  mutate(gid = ceiling(row_number() / 5)) %>%
  group_by(gid) %>%
  summarize(concatenated_text = str_c(Data, collapse = ",")) %>%
  separate(concatenated_text, into = c("LocA", "Value1", "Value2", "Loc", "Value3"), sep=",")
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer as well. It makes be realize I need to dig deeper into `stringr`. I hadn't considered `str_c` with `separate` within a group.